# How can I convert a json string to a scala map?

Tags: json, scala, jackson, json4s

I have a nested json whose structure is not defined. It can be different each time I run since I am reading from a remote file. I need to convert this json into a map of type `Map[String, Any]`. I tried to look into json4s and jackson parsers but they don't seem to solve this issue I have.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Example string:

```
{"body":{
    "method":"string",
    "events":"string",
    "clients":"string",
    "parameter":"string",
    "channel":"string",
    "metadata":{
        "meta1":"string",
        "meta2":"string",
        "meta3":"string"
    }
},
"timestamp":"string"}
```

The level of nesting can be arbitrary and not predefined.
To help with the use case:
  I have a Map[String,Any] which I need to store in a file as backup. So I convert  it to a json string and store it in a file. Now everytime I get new data, I need to get the json from the file, convert it to a map again and perform some computation. I cannot store the map in memory since I would lose that if my job fails.
I need a solution that would convert the json string back to the original map I had before i converted it.

Comment: why don't you use JSON.parseRaw ?

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON and any other helpful code? or info?

Comment: How can you serialize `Any`?

Answer (score 24):

I tried the following method with `json4s` 3.2.11 and it works:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

//...
def jsonStrToMap(jsonStr: String): Map[String, Any] = {
  implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

  parse(jsonStr).extract[Map[String, Any]]
}
```

Maybe you didn't define the `implicit val` of type `Formats`? Note also that you don't need to have an `implicit val` within every and each method as long as it's *findable* in the scope.

Comment: Hey @lambdista, The code looks perfect. and I want to implement this as a custom function in spark but spark data frames doesn't support "any" ref and I tried the same with String,String but it doesn't seem to be working. Do you have any Idea how can we make type specific? Thanks

Comment: @game_changer A bit late, but you can cast it as a `Map[String, String]`. I do the following to parse flat json from spark configuration properties `if (jsonMap.keySet.forall(_.isInstanceOf[String])) jsonMap.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]`. I was using `JSON.parseFull` back then (deprecated), which return `Some(map: Map[_, _])`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code to parse a JSON string into a `Map[String, Any]`

```
import org.json4s._ 
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val jsonMap = parse(jsonString).values.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
```

However, this is **not typesafe** and hence should be used with caution when extracting values from the map.

Comment: What's the import for `parse`?

Comment: @ottovon import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._